# Shrink image in iphone 7 xamarin ios?

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, ios-camera

I am working in xamarin.ios. I am capturing a picture with help of camera and trying to upload it on server. But when I am trying to upload it on server I am getting "TargetInvocationException". But when I am running same code on Ipad everything is working fine.

Following is the code :

```
  Camera.TakePicture(this, (obj) =>
            {
                var photo = obj.ValueForKey(new NSString("UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage")) as UIImage;
                Byte[] myByteArray;
                using (NSData imageData = photo.AsJPEG(0.0f))
                {
                    //myByteArray = imageData.ToArray();
                    myByteArray = new Byte[imageData.Length];
                    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(imageData.Bytes, myByteArray, 0, Convert.ToInt32(imageData.Length));
                }

                ImageLoaderPopup imageLoader = new ImageLoaderPopup(this, selectedWorkOrder, myByteArray, title);
                imageLoader.PopUp(true, delegate { });
            });
```

Does anyone know why I am facing this problem? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you add the whole stacktrace from the `TargetInvocationException` you're seeing?

Answer (score 0):

You might be having problem with the size of the image returned by the Picker. Images taken with the iPhone 7 are huge in size.

You just need to scale down the original image before uploading it using the Scale method and setting the size you find acceptable.

```
var smallImage = image.Scale(new CGSize(1280, 720)); //Or the size you need.
```

***UPDATE***

All you need is the Scale method mentioned above.

The big advantage of Xamarin being Open Source is that you can look at the internals any time you have a doubt.

https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/blob/master/src/UIKit/UIImage.cs#L66